# Yii2 Gridview Actioncolumn Layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, gridview, yii2

It is related to the style.  When there are more columns in the gridview, the layout of the actioncolumn will become vertical (see attached pic).  How can I change it to be horizontal?  I cannot find out why it became vertical in the Bootstrap css.

Thanks!

[vertical layout of actioncolumn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbvXF.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to force style width:

```
[
     'class' => ActionColumn::className(),
     'contentOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
           return ['style' => 'min-width:150px'];
     }
]
```

Change the width as you need.

Comment: Thank you!  It works great!  Is there a way to set it directly in the style sheet?

Comment: Sure! In contentOptions you can return ['class' => 'yourClass']